# JWT, websockets and client-server through the web

Tags: websocket, jwt

We're building a web service with web server and PC clients. Client programs connect to the web server and send some data over websockets.  There is no user interaction in the client, no passwords or logins. It just send some data related to customer's account.

What we're concerned about is should we use JWT for preventing client program or traffic hijacking or not?

All articles we've read are about browsers <> web servers but not programs <> web servers.

thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: To verify the message authenticity, you verify JWT signature - that's its purpose (signature's). If the man in the middle is able to produce a valid signature, that means signing key is leaked - that scenario should be very unlikely to happen, ever, since the assumption is that signing key isn't something you leak out of the blue. Therefore, if signature is fine, JWT came from the correct source and wasn't tampered with. You can sign the token with symmetric key or with private key. Distribute your public key to other apps to verify the signature.

Comment: A JWT should be issued after a proof of authentication. If you have not identification method then your problem is previous, how are you going to identify your PC clients ?

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, to avoid other client making request to your **websocket server** you can use JWT. You don't mentioned what technologies are you using. Here an example with express and socket.io. 
1) The client send the **jwt** on query params.
2) The server verify the **jwt** signature.

```
import express from "express";
import socket from "socket.io";
import http from 'http';

const server = http.createServer(app);  
const io = socket(server);
io.use( async (socket, next) => {   

  if(!socket.handshake.query)
    next(new Error('Not Authenticated'));

  const token = socket.handshake.query.token; 
  const encUsrId =  socket.handshake.query.pcClientToken; //maybe
  try{
      let hasErrors;

      if(token)
        hasErrors = await jwt.validateJSON(token); //validate with your own function.     

      next();
  }
  catch(ex){    
    next(new Error('Not a valid JWT'));
  }
});
```